# How best to manage Java Swing pop-up forms?

Tags: java, swing

I am currently porting my Android app to a desktop app using Java (Swing, NetBeans).
I need a main java window and several pop-up forms for user IO. In the android app I have been using activities, eg: `startActivity(anotherActivity)`. I am currently using a JFrame for each pop-up form in the PC app I have been using `setVisible` to simulate opening the forms from menu actions and other event logic, but hitting the close button on any of the pop-up forms closes the entire app, not just the form. Should I be using something other than `setVisible(true|false)`? Should I be using something other than JFrames such as a JPanel or JDialog? Should I override `close()` on my child forms to do `setVisible(false)`?  Unfortunately, I am learning Java, Swing, and NetBeans on the fly so the best approach to these types of problems is not obvious (to me).

Edit: Why is the auto generated code in `initComponents()` set to `EXIT_ON_CLOSE` when the `defaultCloseOperation` is set to `HIDE` in the swing form properties?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably want to adjust the default close operation, to just hide the frame instead of quitting the app:

```
  setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.HIDE_ON_CLOSE);
```

**Resources**

- [JFrame docs](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JFrame.html#setDefaultCloseOperation(int))

Comment: I verified that the defaultCloseOperation is set to HIDE in the form properties, but the auto generated code in initComponents() is set to EXIT_ON_CLOSE. Is this a JavaBeans defect? Is there a workaround?

Comment: HIDE is working now. Not getting the EXIT_ON_CLOSE in initComponents any more. Do not know exactly why.